# How do I create a package from an existing notebook?

Tags: notebooks, packages

I have a notebook containing some functions, for example:

```
f[x_] := 2*x
g[x_] := x^2
```

Now I would like to convert this notebook to a package, `functions.m`, which I can call with `Get["functions.m"]` inside other notebooks, making the functions `f[x]` and `g[x]` available.

How can I do this without writing the package from scratch?

In the File menu there is a sub-menu Save As -> Package, but if I save it, and load it with`Get["functions.m"]`, nothing seems to happen in the new notebook; i.e., when I try to use the functions, I get:

```
f[x]
```

> ```
> f[x]
> ```

I guess there is something else that I need to do besides simply saving the notebook containing the function definitions as a package?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you save a notebook as a package, the only cells that are setup to be evaluated when the package is loaded are Initialization cells. If you change the cell style to the **code** style, the initialization property is set automatically (this style has the shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>) and the cells are distinguished by a darker background. You can also do this by marking the cell, right clicking and selecting "Initialization Cell".

Comment: btw, congrats on 10k! :)

Comment: @rm-rf Thank you. :)

Answer (score 22):

If you plan to keep developing the package, you can set up your notebook options so that this is all taken care of automatically.

To have your notebook saved as a package every time you save, open the option inspector and, for your notebook, set Notebook Options->File Options->AutoGeneratedPackage to True. Or, in the front-end, you can type

```
SetOptions[Notebooks["<notebook name>.nb"][[1]],AutoGeneratedPackage->Automatic]
```

There is also an option to make new cells initialization cells by default. In the option inspector it is Cell Options->Evaluation Options->InitializationCell (set it to True). The front-end command can be deduced from what is above.

I don't like making my initialization cells code-styled because it seems to disable Mathematica's automatic line-splitting. If you want that, however, change Cell Options->New Cell Defaults->DefaultNewCellStyle to "Code". Why some options have symbol values and some have string values is a mystery to me. You may also want to set DefaultDuplicateCellStyle, the function of which is also a mystery to me.

Comment: I am very happy with this method but there seems to be one downside. It does not preserve headings (nor text cells). On the other hand `Save As` `Package` does preserve these. Is it possible to get the same behavior in an automated method like the above? See also my question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/249494/45020.

Answer (score 13):

You can do this with the [Save](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Save.html) function.

First define some symbols in a notebook:

```
f[x_] := 2^x-1
g[x_] := 1/f[x]
```

Evaluate the definitions.

Now use Save to write them to a file:

```
Save["functions.m", {f, g}]
```

Now f, g, and all their dependencies have been written to the file.

Loading the file with `Get["functions.m"]` will load the definitions into the kernel.

Comment: What directory does this go into? It seems to go into a random one of the directories in $Path. Is there some way to change which directory this saves to by default?

Comment: Directory[] returns the current working directory, change it with SetDirectory[]. Be aware this pushes onto a directory stack, go back to previous with ResetDirectory[]. You can change the default by putting a SetDirectory call in $UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m

Comment: You can also provide an absolute path to Save. But just like anywhere else, relative paths are relative to the current working directory, which is what Directory[] tells you and SetDirectory can change.

Comment: `NotebookDirectory[]` returns the path the actual notebook is in. You can save the `.m` file in the same directory where its "mother notebook" resides by invoking `Save[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "functions.m"}], {f,g}]`.