# No names when loading package

Tags: packages

I want to use mu own package. 
This is the procedure I take:

1) In Mathematica notebook I put the following code taken from [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574710/integrating-notebooks-to-mathematicas-documentation-center)

```
BeginPackage["SOPackage`"];
AddTwo::usage = 
"AddTwo[\!\(\*StyleBox[\"a\", \"TI\"]\), \!\(\*StyleBox[\"b\", \"TI\
\"]\)] returns \!\(\*StyleBox[\"a\", \"TI\"]\)+\!\(\*StyleBox[\"b\", \
\"TI\"]\).";
DotTwo::usage = 
"DotTwo[\!\(\*StyleBox[\"a\", \"TI\"]\), \!\(\*StyleBox[\"b\", \"TI\
\"]\)] returns \!\(\*StyleBox[\"a\", \"TI\"]\)*\!\(\*StyleBox[\"b\", \
\"TI\"]\).";
AddTwo::argnum = 
"AddTwo was called with `1` arguments. It expected 2.";
DotTwo::argnum = 
"DotTwo was called with `1` arguments. It expected 2.";

Begin["`Private`"];

AddTwo[a_, b_] := a + b
AddTwo[args___] := (Message[AddTwo::argnum, Length[{args}]]; $Failed)
DotTwo[a_, b_] := a*b
DotTwo[args___] := (Message[DotTwo::argnum, Length[{args}]]; $Failed)

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

2) Go to SaveAs SOPackage.m

3) Put the file in $UserBaseDirectory/Applications

4) load the package with << SOPackage`

The problem is that nothing is loaded (I checked with Names["SOPackage`*"]). How to do this right?

I am using Mathematica 10.1 on Linux.

Comment: See [(31302)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31302)

Comment: You quoted  ``Names["SOPackages`*"]``, while it should've been ``Names["SOPackage`*"]``. Could it be just a simple typo?

Comment: yes a typo. Sorry

Comment: So, does the correct command give you the function names all right?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( empty.

Comment: Ok, I missed the point. Given that you work within nb, link given by @ilian is most relevant. But, is there any reason you don't just use any text editor to save this contents to a file? It seems  a much simpler way to me.

Comment: Ok :) Thank You. When I write in Mathematica notebook I should select "Initialization Cell". I can also write everything from scratch in gedit and save with .m extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All cells in a notebook saved as a .m file which is intended to be loaded with `Get` or `Needs` must be initialization cells.