# Fail to Create a package

Tags: packages

This is rather basic.

In an empty notebook I type in a single cell

```
BeginPackage["fun`"]
Unprotect @@ Names["fun`*"];
ClearAll @@ Names["fun`*"];
f::usage = "f[x]"
Begin["`Private`"]
f[x_] := Module[{}, Sin[x^2]];
End[]
Protect @@ Names["fun`*"];
EndPackage[]
```

I select the cell and change to become an initialization cell.
When I save the notebook, there is the option to save it as an Mathematica package.
But I have read somewhere that when you save it for the first time it should appear a pop-up men asking about an AUTO SAVE choice.

But, this menu does not appear. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
There is an answer to a similar query [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31302/how-do-i-create-a-package-from-an-existing-notebook)

```
SetOptions[Notebooks["<notebook name>.nb"][[1]],AutoGeneratedPackage->Automatic]
```

[Strangely](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AutoGeneratedPackage.html):

**This function has not been fully integrated into the long-term Wolfram Language, and is subject to change.**

AutoGeneratedPackage
is an option for notebooks that specifies whether a package is automatically created when a notebook that contains initialization cells or groups is saved.

(...since 1999...)

Comment: IMO, this question is better asked of Wolfram Research than asked here. It may be that the behavior you allude to changed when WRI added (in V6?) a template for creating packages to _Mathematica_ (File > New > Package). I recommend  using this template to build a package than converting notebooks.