# Export a Package (.m) from a Notebook (.nb)

Tags: export, packages

I recently started creating *Mathematica* packages. I find it easiest to develop functions in a *Notebook* (*.nb* file). This allows me to add sections, comments and examples.

I don't want to duplicate code, certainly not by copy/pasting my function from the *.nb* file to the *.m* package file. So I would prefer automatically generate *Package* code from a *Notebook*.

Are there direct methods of generating a *.m* file? Alternative methods of developping *Packages* in a *Notebook* environment?

The following is just an example to illustrate one possible method to avoid duplication of code. Imagine that I have a *.nb* with the following function:

```
toSquare = Function[{x}, x^2]
```

Now I want to export this *Input* as pure code, for example by adding a button which exports this function to a *.m* file:

```
Button["Export as package", toPackage["packageName.m", ...]]
```

This should generate the file *packageName.m* with the following content:

```
BeginPackage["Square`"];
toSquare::usage="toSquare[x] squares numbers.";
toSquare=Function[{x},x^2];
EndPackage[]
```

Can *Inputs* be converted to strings? Can *Functions* be converted to strings? Exporting strings to a *.m* file seems slightly hacky to me, so if there are alternatives, I'd prefer that.

Comment: closely related: [cell to string](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1319/5478), [notebook to a package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31302/5478)

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate of [noebook to a package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31302/how-do-i-create-a-package-from-an-existing-notebook). Especially the [Save](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Save.html) function is a good answer to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing your package in a notebook is the preferred way for many (perhaps most?). To generate the .m from the .nb all you need to do is make the Input cells that you want also be Initialization cells: Right-click on the cell bracket and use the check-box.
Then use  File -> Save As  and choose .m. That will not change your notebook in any way, it will just write a .m file that contains all the initialization cells that you wanted.

Even better, you can skip all the Save As stuff by tracking down the option for automatically saving a .m file if your notebook has *any* initialization cells in it:

Edit -> Preferences -> Option Inspector -> Notebook Options -> File Options -> AutogeneratePackage

Comment: Yes, this is ideal. Thanks. This can also be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31302/how-do-i-create-a-package-from-an-existing-notebook), so I'm voting to close my own question.

Comment: Another great thing about using the autosaving .m from an .nb approach is you can make nicely formatted usage messages without any hassle with StyleBox or SubscriptBox.

Answer (score 1):

I created a short function which grabs the previously evaluated *Input Cell* as a string, based on *Mathematica*'s `InString[]` function:

```
getInputAsString = Function[{},StringReplace[ToString[InputForm[MakeExpression[ToExpression[InString[]],StandardForm]]],RegularExpression["HoldComplete\[(.*)\]"]->"$1;"]];
```

This can be combined with the following function which exports a list of such *input strings* as a *.m* package file.

```
toPackage = Function[{fullPath,contextName,inputStrings},With[{output=StringJoin[{"BeginPackage[\"",contextName,"\"];\n",Riffle[inputStrings,"\n"],"\nEndPackage[]"}]},Export[fullPath,output,"Text"];]]
```

The following example illustrates the use:

```
toSquare::usage = "toSquare[x] squares numbers." (*"toSquare[x] squares numbers."*)
toSquareUsageString = getInputAsString[] (*"toSquare::usage = \"toSquare[x] squares numbers.\";"*)
```

and

```
toSquare = Function[{x}, x^2] (*Function[{x}, x^2]*)
toSquareString = getInputAsString[] (*"toSquare = Function[{x}, x^2];"*)
```

Finally

```
toPackage[
    ToString[NotebookDirectory[]] <>"PackageSquare.m",
    "Square`",
    {toSquareUsageString, toSquareString}
]
```

generates a file "PackageSquare.m" in the same directory with content:

```
BeginPackage["Square`"];
toSquare::usage = "toSquare[x] squares numbers.";
toSquare = Function[{x}, x^2];
EndPackage[]
```

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, I find this method via strings slightly hacky. If you know a better method, I will accept that as the answer.