# Automatically export .nb to a package upon saving while preserving section headings

Tags: packages, formatting

Is it possible to automatically export a `.m` package when I save my `.nb` as can be done using the option `"AutoGeneratedPackage->Automatic"` see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31323/45020 but **presrving the section headings and text cells**? (Still excluding non-initialization cells.) Unfortunately the AutoGeneratePackage does not include headings by default.

It was pointed out to me by Jason B. that the default export using `Save As` `Package` does preserve the headings as I would like. Can we get this behavior also in some automated method (ideally exporting every time I save the `.nb`).

---

About my edit: Originally I did not know that `Save As` `Package` does preserve the headings. I assumed that the behavior of `"AutoGeneratedPackage->Automatic"` was the default. While `Save As` does offer a solution I would much prefer an automatically exporting one.

Comment: Try `File->Save As->` and select Package from the dropdown menu.  Just be aware that any code you want to save to the package *must* be in a `Code` cell.

Comment: Right, so I know the standard ways of exporting a package. My question is explicitly about a way to include headings and text cells. As far as I know these are mutually exclusive and so cannot be `Code` cells.

Comment: When I try the standard way of exporting a package, text cells and Section/Subsection/etc are preserved, is this not the case when you tried it?

Comment: I apologize. I thought I was using the equivalent of a standard export. Clearly you are correct and this question is based on a misunderstanding on my part. I am using `"AutoGeneratedPackage->Automatic"` (see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31323/45020). 
This automatic method does not preserve text cells and headings. I will edit my question to ask the better question of how to automatically generate a package that preserves these.